# Can I replace a HiddenField with a private variable in ASP.NET page class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been handed over a ASP.NET web application for support and development. While going through the code of webforms, I see

```
<asp:HiddenField .../>
```

elements in some pages, mostly for storing certain IDs (employee ID, office ID etc.). I am thinking to replace them with class level variables in the same Page class where they are defined (in code-behind).

Can it cause some problem in the application execution?

Comment: Question is, WHY do you want to do this? seems like a hack or a workaround for something... you need to develop an elegant solution...what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The page-class will not retain the value of the variable during postbacks, your solution wont work. The hiddenfield is there for a reason, to post the id back to the server in a button click for example (postback).

Comment: Why don't you try it? But I expect it does cause harm. The hidden fields are most often used to carry state between the client and server on postbacks. Your private fields are long gone when the user click submit on a button.

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas i was thinking to revamp the code with less clutter and make it simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using variables won't work because the values isn't maintained during a postback.

In this case i would use properties combined with ViewState.

```
private int employeeID
{
    get { return (int)(ViewState["employeeID"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["employeeID"] = value; }
}
```

That maintains the value during a postback and has less overhead than the `HiddenField` Control AND in ViewState you are able to store whole Objects

If you want to keep the value during the whole User-Session, replace `ViewState` with `Session` to use the SessionState

Comment: By less overhead do you mean that it is not passed from client to server and back to client, on postbacks? or do you mean something else ?

Comment: incorrect. ViewState has MORE overhead. I have answered these questions many times but now would rather give a link: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate